# Como plotar apenas uma parte de uma variável Posixct?

Tags: r, ggplot2, posix

Eu tenho um df com 2 variáveis. A primeira é um contador de tempo que chega à 9min em uma taxa de aquisição de 1000Hz (Portanto, é enorme 540 mil linhas). A segunda variável é uma medida eletrofisiológica em uS (micro siemens). Seguem as 20 primeiras linhas abaixo:

```
> dput(head(SC,20))

structure(list(time = c(0, 0.001, 0.002, 0.003, 0.004, 0.005, 
0.006, 0.007, 0.008, 0.009, 0.01, 0.011, 0.012, 0.013, 0.014, 
0.015, 0.016, 0.017, 0.018, 0.019), Conductance = c(0, 0, 0, 
0.01, 0.01, 0.02, 0.03, 0.04, 0.05, 0.07, 0.07, 0.08, 0.09, 0.09, 
0.09, 0.09, 0.1, 0.09, 0.09, 0.09)), row.names = c(NA, 20L), class = "data.frame")
```

Converti a variável "time" para um Posixct e preciso plotar num gráfico. Contudo, não quero plotar toda a variável Time. Somente parte dela. Não tenho habilidade com Posixct e não sei como editar o "xlim" do gráfico.

```
require(lubridate)
SC$time <- as_datetime(SC$time)

> head(SC$time)
[1] "1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC" "1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC"
[3] "1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC" "1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC"
[5] "1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC" "1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC"

> tail(SC$time,10)
 [1] "1970-01-01 00:09:13 UTC" "1970-01-01 00:09:13 UTC"
 [3] "1970-01-01 00:09:13 UTC" "1970-01-01 00:09:13 UTC"
 [5] "1970-01-01 00:09:13 UTC" "1970-01-01 00:09:13 UTC"
 [7] "1970-01-01 00:09:13 UTC" "1970-01-01 00:09:13 UTC"
 [9] "1970-01-01 00:09:13 UTC" "1970-01-01 00:09:13 UTC"
```

Usei o seguinte código mas ele leva toda a informação, inclusive o formato do eixo x não fica bom pq inclui HORA (que não é relevante):

```
pl <- ggplot(SC, aes(x = time, Conductance)) + geom_line()
```

[image]

Como fazer o ajuste do eixo x para qualquer unidade de tempo (janela) desejada? Por Exemplo: somente do 2,5 minutos até 6,5 minutos (janela de 5min portanto).

Comment: Compartilhe seus dados utilizando o resultado de `dput(head(SC, 20))` que isso irá facilitar muito a vida de quem for tentar te ajudar.

Comment: Pode postar com os valores depois de colocar em Posixct? E o resultado esperado é só com os minutos no xlim?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Olha, o gráfico que tu mandou a imagem tá em minutos não? Se vai de 0 a 9 minutos o gráfico mostra de 00:00 a 09:00, sendo minutos:segundos.

Mas enfim, se quiser ter certeza que é pra manter os segundos ou minutos é só usar `minute()` do pacote dplyr. Aqui tô usando `second()` porque os primeiros 20 dados são todos no primeiro minuto.

Mas o que eu faria pra conseguir o que você quer seria usar o `filter()` do pacote `dplyr` pra selecionar os dados, fazer o gráfico e no final mudar a escala se eu não achasse a automática boa.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

SC %>% 
  mutate(second = second(time)) %>% 
  filter(between(second,.005,.012)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(second(time), Conductance)) + 
  geom_line() +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(.005, .012, by = .002))
```

Outra opção seria fazer a operação no gráfico. Você pode usar `xlim` pra escolher a região do x do gráfico.

```
ggplot(SC, aes(second(time), Conductance)) + 
  geom_line() +
  xlim(c(.005,.012))
```

Ou utilizar `coord_cartesian` pra dar um zoom na região que você quer e depois, se precisar, mudar a escala.

```
ggplot(SC, aes(second(time), Conductance)) + 
  geom_line() +
  coord_cartesian(xlim=c(.005,.012)) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(.005, .012, by = .002))
```

Comment: De fato o gráfico que mandei já estava em minutos, contudo, como não estava conseguindo usar o "xlim" com a variável Posixct. Eu preciso cortar os 9min em pedaços menores. Pude observar na sua resposta que em ambas as possibilidades: "xlim"; "coord_cartesian" e "scale_x_continuous" as operações foram com a variável em sua forma numérica (.005, .012) portanto, vou encontrar os valores que representam os minutos os quais devo trabalhar. Minha esperança era que se podia chamar um intervalo de um objeto Poisxct diretamente usando algo parecido com %M%S.

Comment: Veja a documentação do pacote `scales`. Este pacote funciona muito bem para fazer este tipo de formatação que tu deseja.